# CSS animation acting three different ways in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, css-animations, keyframe

Here's what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/t5p8ypxs/9/

And here is my css:

```
.wrapper{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.square{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-animation: imageFrames01 5s ease-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: imageFrames01 5s ease-out infinite;
    animation: imageFrames01 5s ease-out infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes imageFrames01 {
     0% {
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
  }
  15.15152% {
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30.66667% {
    left: 154%;
    opacity: 0;
    top: -98%;
  }
  30.67667% {
    left: -63%;
    opacity: 1;
    top: -138%;
  }
  90.48485% {
    left: -63%;
    opacity: 1;
    top: -138%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageFrames01 {
  /*Same as above in @-moz-keyframes*/
}

@keyframes imageFrames01 {
 /*Same as above in @-moz-keyframes*/
}
```

Safari is the only browser to animate this as I would expect.

1. Move in from the top-left
2. Move out to the top-right
3. Repeat to infinity

In Chrome I get this:

1. Just appears, with no animation
2. Move out to the top-right
3. Repeat to infinity

Firefox is worst with no position animations.  Only opacity...

Any ideas.  Why is this?

I am using Safari 8, Chrome 42, and Firefox 33

Answer (score 0):

`-moz-animation: imageFrames01 66s ease-out infinite;`

Try to change the 66s to 5s like the others for Mozilla...

Comment: Oops, that was last minute copy and paste, as my full real animation is 66s. Fixed that.  But, regardless, Firefox is using animation without the vender prefix.  It has been since FF 16 -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Browser_compatibility